# How to make a static TextView over the ImageButton in ScrollView?

Tags: android, xml, textview, scrollview, imagebutton

```
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/busfoto2" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bus Locations"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
```

I tried but the text still moving when I scroll the screen, I want to fix it on specific ImageButton

Comment: Can you post your layout?

Answer (score 1):

Put Button and TextView in to FrameLayout like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/busfoto2"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bus Locations"/></FrameLayout>
```